# найти подходящий мд5, перебирая строки

Tags: c#

вопрос такой: как сделать чтобы софт генерировал пароль длинной 4 знака и вычислял хеш мд5 от каждой строки, и потом когда я прописываю первые 2 знака от пароля там допустим "c5", то софт выводил пароли эти у которых хеш начинается с "c5" ? Этот вопрос повторяю т.к. нет до сих пор точного ответа

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40982/discussion-on-question-by-wiz-khalifaaaaa---5--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе комментариев:

Имеем алфавит: a-z A-Z 0-9 (62 знака)

Нужно получить все пароли длиной 5 знаков.

Оценим масштаб трагедии: 62^5 = 916132832 паролей что меньше чем 2^63, а значит можно воспользоваться простым переводом из 10-чной в 62-ичную систему счисления.

алфавит зададим строкой:

```
string alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
long startPassNum = 0;
long endPassNum = 916132832;
string resultPass;    

for (long current = startPassNum; current < endPassNum; current++)
{
    //теперь переведем в число в нужное представление
    StringBuilder pass = new StringBuilder(5);
    while((current % alph.Length) > 0)
    {
        pass.Insert(0, alph[current % alph.Length]);
        current = current / alph.Length;
    }
    //первую половину всех паролей придется дополнять до нужного числа знаков
    while(pass.Length<5)
    {
        pass.Insert(0, alph[0]);
    }
    resultPass = pass.ToString();
    pass.Clear();
    // тут что-то делаем с паролем из resultPass
}
```

Такой подход позволяет получить пароль просто по его номеру, что делает, заодно, упрощает и случайную генерацию, сводя ее к генерации случайного номера пароля.

Метод хорошо распараллеливается на потоки при необходимости простым разбиением на интервалы номеров паролей.

Comment: то есть на твой взгляд это самый короткий из возможных ?

Comment: в данном случае да, для бОльших длин паролей или алфавита 2^63 может не хватить и придется что-то мудрить, а тут все просто

Comment: он, к тому же, еще и относительно быстрый. В принципе даже без потоков за несколько часов должен справиться на хорошем железе. На крайний случай можно `for` заменить на `Parallel.For()`, пример тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: только тогда объявление resultPass нужно внутрь цикла убрать

Comment: я про код ниже который

Comment: для 20 знаков в принципе да, во всяком случае по скорости, но бессмысленность полного перебора 20-значных паролей я наглядно показал =) ни какое железо не осилит за разумное время

Comment: но как можно ЭТОТ КОД СОКРАТИТЬ, ЧТО ПРЯМО и оставить ?